# Ruby sockets not receiving all the messages

Tags: ruby, sockets, irc

I wrote a little script on Ruby to connect and login on a IRC server, but when the IRC server sends out a new message, the socket doesn't receive it, for example, a log is:

```
:irc.someserver.net NOTICE Auth :*** Looking up your hostname...
:irc.someserver.net NOTICE Auth :Welcome to someserver Net!
:irc.someserver.net 003 brobot :This server was created 15:40:35 Mar 28 2012
:irc.someserver.net 005 brobot MAXTARGETS=20 MODES=20 NETWORK=Studio NICKLEN=32 Net PREFIX=(ov)@+ STATUSMSG=@+ TOPICLEN=308 VBANLIST WALLCHOPS WALLVOICES :are supported by this server
:irc.someserver.net 372 brobot :- Welcome To the someserver Chat Server. Please Select the #Team Channel.
:irc.someserver.net 252 brobot 1 :operator(s) online
:irc.someserver.net 265 brobot :Current Local Users: 5  Max: 5
:irc.someserver.net 353 brobot = #brobot_dev :@Pablo brobot 
:Pablo!Pablo@ip-10-1-1-6.ec2.internal PRIVMSG #brobot_dev :f
PING :irc.someserver.net
```

That's a sample log, it looks ok, but on `:Pablo!Pablo@ip-10-1-1-6.ec2.internal PRIVMSG #brobot_dev :f` is when it misses messages. For example I send 5 messages and the client only receives 1. This is the client code:

```
require 'socket'      # Sockets are in standard library

hostname = '10.1.1.1'
port = 6667

server = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

loop {
    server.flush
    puts server.gets.chomp

    if server.gets.chomp =~ /:.*NOTICE Auth :\*\*\* Found your hostname/
        server.puts "USER brobot brobot brobot brobot\r\nNICK brobot\r\n"
    elsif server.gets.chomp =~ /:\S* 26*/
        server.puts "JOIN #brobot_dev\r\n"
    end
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
puts server.gets.chomp
```

collects the data the server has sent, prints it, and discards it. Then you call the same thing twice more and each time new data is collected. Try this:

```
@response = server.gets.chomp
# use contents of @response instead of calling #gets again
if @response =~ /:.*NOTICE Auth :\*\*\* Found your hostname/
    server.print "USER brobot brobot brobot brobot\r\nNICK brobot\r\n"
elsif @response =~ /:\S* 26*/
    server.print "JOIN #brobot_dev\r\n"
end
```

I've replaced your 'puts's with 'print's because you're including the \r\n in the string.